# Green's function on the whole line

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, greens-function

The function $\phi/2$ is a Green's function for the operator $1-\partial_x^2$ where $\phi=e^{-|x|}$. Thus, formally, the solution to 
$$
y-y''=f(x)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)
$$
on the whole line is
$$
y=\frac{1}{2}\phi\ast f,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)
$$ 
where $\ast$ denotes convolution.

My question: how bad can $f$ be for  (2) to define a solution to Equation (1)? If $f$ is smooth and bounded for example, it works. How about, for example, if $f$ is

(i) $H^1(\mathbb{R})$?

(ii) $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ (Bounded and continuous)?

(iii) $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

(iv) ${\mbox{L}}_{1,\,{\mbox{loc}}}(\mathbb{R})$ (locally integrable) with the restriction that $\phi\ast f$ exists?

Answer (score 0):

You need $ \phi *f $ , and $\phi *f'$ or $\phi' *f$ to exist.

Green functions are meaningful in the context of distributions, so the distributional derivative $\phi *f'$ or $\phi' *f$ need to exist.

Comment: Are you saying that as long as phi' * f exists, then phi*f defines a solution to the equation?